# Perform an async task with a web worker JavaScript

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I want to show a loading icon while a task is being performed and then hide the icon after it has been performed. I need to use a web worker for the loading icon to show. The admin at [This forum post](http://www.telerik.com/forums/app-showloading()-and-app-hideloading()#LdCLln8PNEiMp9eTApA_vQ) said to use a web worker.

This is the code to execute in the web worker:

```
function getTheClients(xml) {
    console.log(xml);
                var client = xml.getElementsByTagName("WebClientList");
                if(client.length === 0) {
                    $("#noClients" + platform).empty();
                    $("#noClients" + platform).append('<p style="margin-top:40px;margin-bottom:20px;text-align:center;">No clients at ' +
                        getSelectedDropDownOptionName("allVillagesDropDown") + ', ' + 
                        getSelectedDropDownOptionName("allLocationsDropDown") + '.</p>');
                    $("#noClients" + platform).attr("style", "display: block");
                    $("#theClientsList" + platform).attr("style", "display: none");
                } else {
                     $("#noClients" + platform).attr("style", "display: none");
                    $("#theClientsList" + platform).attr("style", "display: block");
                }
                for (i=0; i < client.length; i++) {
                    var firstName = client[i].getElementsByTagName("givenName")[0].childNodes[0];
                    var lastName = client[i].getElementsByTagName("familyName")[0].childNodes[0];
                    var oid = client[i].getElementsByTagName("oid")[0].childNodes[0];
                    var nhi = client[i].getElementsByTagName("nhi")[0].childNodes[0];
                    var dwelling = client[i].getElementsByTagName("dwelling")[0].childNodes[0];
                    var photo = client[i].getElementsByTagName("photo")[0].childNodes[0];


                    if (!photo) {
                        photo = "";
                    } else {
                        photo = photo.nodeValue;
                    }
                    firstName = firstName ? firstName.nodeValue : "";
                    lastName = lastName ? lastName.nodeValue : "";
                    oid = oid ? oid.nodeValue : "";
                    nhi = nhi ? nhi.nodeValue : "";
                    dwelling = dwelling ? dwelling.nodeValue : "";
                    var letterDwelling = dwelling ? dwelling[0].toUpperCase() : "";
                    var letterLastName = lastName ? lastName[0].toUpperCase() : "";
                    console.log(photo);
                    dataSource.add({photo: photo, firstName: firstName,lastName: lastName,oid: oid,nhi: nhi,dwelling: dwelling, letterDwelling: letterDwelling, letterLastName: letterLastName});
                }
                if (clientListViewHasNotLoaded) {
                    searchFilter = "lastName";
                    listGroup = "letterLastName"
                    console.log("e");
                    $("#theClientsList" + platform).append('<ul id="flat-listview' + platform + '" class="listView' + platform + '" style="width: 100%; margin-bottom:10px; margin-top:10px;"></ul>');

                    initListView({
                                     field: "lastName",
                                     operator: "startswith",
                                     placeholder: "Search by last name"
                                 }
                        );

                    $("#flat-listview" + platform).data("kendoMobileListView").setDataSource(dataSource);
                    clientListViewHasNotLoaded = false;
                }
}
```

here is the code I'm using to create a web worker, before I take the next step and incorporate my above function:

the script (webServiceScript.js):

```
self.onmessage = function(event) {
    var results = event.data;
    // do something
    // Done:
    postMessage(results);
};
```

The calling code:

```
var worker = new Worker('scripts/webServiceScript.js');
worker.onmessage = function(event) {
    // Do something with event.data, then hide the spinner.
    app.showLoading();
};
app.hideLoading();
worker.postMessage({args: ' foo bar '});
```

I would like to incorporate my function at the top of the question into the script file (to be used in a web worker). When I incorporate my above function into the script, I need to pass my variable called xml.

Any help greatly appreciated, I'm struggling to understand the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers).

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @jfriend00 How do I perform a basic task asynchronously using a web worker. Then substitute the basic task, for my function at the top of the question, passing in one variable to the async task (xml). The reason for it being async is because It is the only way to get my loading icon to show.

Comment: If you want a loading icon to show, it's much easier to just show the loading icon, then use `setTimeout(func, 1);` to run your function.  No need for webWorkers.  You just need to let the browser to a repaint and `setTimeout()` will do that.

Comment: @jfriend00 Oh okay, thanks. I was using this forum answer as my guide: [link](http://www.telerik.com/forums/app-showloading()-and-app-hideloading()#LdCLln8PNEiMp9eTApA_vQ)

So the setTimeout you suggested will wait one millisecond and perform my function, will it be asynchronous and make the loading icon show?

Comment: @jfriend00 is the syntax like `app.showLoading();
    setTimeout(getTheClients(xml), 1);` then at the end of getTheClients(xml) have `app.hideLoading()`? As The loading icon is not showing with that.

Comment: Use a Web Worker when you want to offload processing to a separate thread, like uploading a large file or running a math-intensive process.

Comment: See my answer for code specifics.

Answer (score 0):

As we were discussing in comments, all you need to do is give the browser a chance to do a repaint.  You can accomplish that with `setTimeout()` like this:

```
app.showLoading()
setTimeout(function() {
    getTheClients(xml);
    app.hideLoading();
}, 1);
```

You can't do `setTimeout(getTheClients(xml), 1);` because that calls `getClients()` right away and then passes the return result from that to `setTimeout()`.  Instead, you have to pass just a function reference to `setTimeout()` as shown above.

Comment: Doesn't make the loading icon appear, unfortunately.

Comment: @btf - then you have other problems which are not evident in the code you've disclosed.  I'd suggest you look in the browser console for JS errors which may be preventing code from running.  This code gives the browser a chance to repaint.  You apparently have other problems too.

Comment: There are no errors in the console. This solution you suggested may not work for Telerik mobile apps. The admin at [this forum post](http://www.telerik.com/forums/app-showloading()-and-app-hideloading()#LdCLln8PNEiMp9eTApA_vQ) said to use a web worker.

Comment: @btf - I have no idea what a Telerik mobile app is and this appears to be the first time you've mentioned this was anything other than a web page.  A web worker is simply not needed (way overly complex) just to get the screen to repaint.  If `showLoading()` needs more than a simple repaint, then your question needs to include that information.  Right now, I'm giving up because your question is simply not clear.

Comment: That's fine. I just want to use a web worker to perform my function that is at the top of this question. I want to use a web worker because that is the way to make the showLoading display according to a Telerik admin, but that information is not really required in order to show me how to use a web worker. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @btf - There are hundreds of examples of webWorkers on the web.  You should build a super simple webWorker based on one of those examples and then add pieces of your code to it.  If you get stuck, you should ask a more specific question than "how to use a webWorker" which is far too broad for StackOverflow.  For starters, you cannot access the DOM from a webWorker at all.